# How do I add fields to a form indefinately with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, onclick

I am new to JavaScript DOM. I found a tutorial at [www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html). I rewrote the code to suit my needs but when I couldn't get it to work, I copied the code from this page directly into a test page. The moreFields function will run onload, but not onclick. The removeFields function does work. I have tested the code in both Firefox and Chromium. It works in Firefox in the tutorial but not even when I copy it verbatim. I even tried copying the source from the tutorial.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var counter = 0;

function moreFields() {
counter++;
var newFields = document.getElementById(\'readroot\').cloneNode(true);
newFields.id = \'\';
newFields.style.display = \'block\';
var newField = newFields.childNodes;
for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
    var theName = newField[i].name
    if (theName)
        newField[i].name = theName + counter;
}
var insertHere = document.getElementById(\'writeroot\');
insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
}

window.onload = moreFields;

// -->
</script>

<div id="readroot" style="display: none">

<input type="button" value="Remove review"
    onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /><br /><br />

<input name="cd" value="title" />

<select name="rankingsel">
    <option>Rating</option>
    <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
    <option value="good">Good</option>
    <option value="ok">OK</option>
    <option value="poor">Poor</option>
    <option value="bad">Bad</option>
</select><br /><br />

<textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="review">Short review</textarea>
<br />Radio buttons included to test them in Explorer:<br />
<input type="radio" name="something" value="test1" />Test 1<br />
<input type="radio" name="something" value="test2" />Test 2

</div>

<form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/show_params.cgi">

<span id="writeroot"></span>

<input type="button" id="moreFields" value="Give me more fields!" />
<input type="submit" value="Send form" />

</form>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I am inputting this in a php variable so I have to escape the "'"s

Comment: You can use " style quotations in javascript.  If those don't need escaping, it'll make the whole thing a lot more readable.

Comment: Your script has syntactical issues, you should not escape `'` using `\'` ex `\'readroot\'` should be `'readroot'` or `"readroot"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code doesn't work because the function moreFields() is not attached to the button #moreFields click event.

Just change the line 19 for

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('moreFields').onclick = function(){ moreFields(); }
    moreFields();
}
```

Comment: +1 There is no need to wrap *moreFields* in a function, you can directly assign a reference. That will also avoid creating unnecessary closures that can cause memory leaks in older browsers.

Comment: @RobG How do I assign a function by reference in Javascript? I am familiar with PHP but I am new to JavaScript. IE $var1 = @$var2;

Comment: @CoreyRay—`...onclick = moreFields;`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (in addition to not including a listener on the button per Lucas' answer) is that you have an element with an ID of "moreFields", so if you have a listener like:

```
<input id="moreFields" ... onclick="moreFields();">
```

then in the listener, *moreFields* references the button itself rather than the function. So either change the name or ID to not clash (the button doesn't need a name or ID anyway), or to call the function as a property of *window*:

```
<input id="moreFields" ... onclick="window.moreFields();">
```

Using *addEventListener* or direct assignment will fix the issue too:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('moreFields').onclick = moreFields;
  moreFields();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems here.

1. You are escaping the `'` with `\'` which is invalid, string literals has to be enclosed with in `''` or `""`.
2. There is no click handler for `morefields` button
3. There is a scoping problem since you have a function and button with id `morefields`

Try

```
<div id="readroot" style="display: none">

    <input type="button" value="Remove review"
    onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /><br /><br />

    <input name="cd" value="title" />

    <select name="rankingsel">
        <option>Rating</option>
        <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
        <option value="good">Good</option>
        <option value="ok">OK</option>
        <option value="poor">Poor</option>
        <option value="bad">Bad</option>
    </select><br /><br />

    <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="review">Short review</textarea>
    <br />Radio buttons included to test them in Explorer:<br />
    <input type="radio" name="something" value="test1" />Test 1<br />
    <input type="radio" name="something" value="test2" />Test 2

</div>

<form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/show_params.cgi">

    <span id="writeroot"></span>

    <input type="button" value="Give me more fields!" onclick="moreFields()"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send form" />

</form>
```

And

```
var counter = 0;

function moreFields() {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name
        if (theName)
            newField[i].name = theName + counter;
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
                                             insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
}

window.onload = moreFields;
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DDFgD/2/)

Comment: Thanks for that input. I was escaping the single quotes because I am outputing this from a PHP variable (using an MVC Framework I am creating. Yes I know I am reinventing the wheel) I didn't know if single or double quotes mattered in Javascript so I used what I saw and escaped them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the moreFields() function as an onclick event to the button.

You can do it this way by changing the existing onload code to this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  moreFields();
  document.getElementById('moreFields').onclick = moreFields;
};
```

We wait to add the onclick until window load because otherwise the HTML button won't have loaded by that time (there is also the DOMContentLoaded event, but one thing at a time...).

You can also add the call to moreFields on your button element, but note that you have to change your ID or otherwise, for INLINE JavaScript (i.e., not in a script tag or separate script file), the element will be exposed as a variable using its ID, and it will try to call the element "moreFields" (and thus give an error) instead of the function `moreFields()`.

```
<input type="button" id="moreFields1" onclick="moreFields()" value="Give me more fields!" />
```

(Or you can do as RobG mentions and explicitly call the moreFields on the window.)